gio open does not use a clean environment
The gio man page states that:

open LOCATION...
Opens files with the default application that is registered to handle files of this type.
[...]
Environment variables will not be set on the application, as it may be an existing process which is activated to handle the new file.

Specifically:

Environment variables will not be set on the application

However:
$ DEBUG=please_unset_me gio open test.txt
$ cat /proc/`pidof xed`/environ | xargs -0 -L1 | grep "DEBUG"
DEBUG=please_unset_me 

Is it a bug or am I missing something?
